# SparkSession taking too long on a local standalone cluster

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

I'm quite new to Big Data and currently I'm learning Apache Spark. I've created a standalone cluster with a master and one slave in the same machine. SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY is set to "1g" and SPARK_LOCAL_IP points to my ip address. So, I wrote a python code to simply create a SparkSession:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from time import time

def main( ):
    start_time = time( )
    sparkSession = ( SparkSession.builder
                                 .master( "spark://nilson:7077" )
                                 .appName( "pyclient" )
                                 .config( "spark.executor.memory", "512m" )
                                 .getOrCreate( ) )

    elapsed_time = time( ) - start_time

    print ("\n\nelapsed time: %.4gs" %elapsed_time)
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main( )
```

It is taking almost 6 seconds, as you can see
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hefpr.png)

So, my question is:

Does it really take this time or there is something missing in my environment variables?

I also tried to read a simple json file which contains just two lines of data. The whole process took almost 13 seconds to open it and print its content.

Thank you.

Comment: yes, it is expected. There are so many background processes spark runs to execute your code, set root log level to debug to print all processes logs.

Answer (score 0):

Spark is engine for large-scale data processing and it does many small house keeping stuff before launching job which you don't see because of logger configuration. Irrespective of data size it runs initial setup steps.

You can start browsing those internal logs by changing logger levels to :ALL, DEBUG, ERROR, INFO, OFF, WARN

e.g. `sc.setLogLevel("ERROR") #default`